# Parallelize a blocking call in Java

Tags: java, parallel-processing, blocking, readline

I am currently using the below code to run a process and print its output from within my own program. My problem is that I'd like to do more than just print the output. However, since the Process being executed scarcely prints output to the console, the commented line is almost never executed because the readLine() method is blocking.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executablePath);
ProcessWatcher pw = new ProcessWatcher(p);
BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while(!pw.isFinished()) {
    String line = output.readLine();
    if(line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    // I want to do something in parallel here
}
```

My problem would be solved if I could give the readLine() call some sort of timeout, or if I could run it in its own Thread. The latter would be preferred, but the former is acceptable. My primary intention is to keep the code simple.

Is there a nice, simple way to parallelize a blocking call, or will I need to create a new class that implements Runnable just for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap you code with.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
///put your code here
}}).start();
```

You cannot do a non-blocking readLine or one with a timeout. In any case, writing code to handle non-blocking connections is usually 10x more complex.  ;)

Comment: That can be made just a tiny bit shorter: new Thread() { public void run() { } }

Comment: I prefer to avoid subclassing Thread. It can lead to confusion. ;)

Comment: The problem I'm having with using a Thread like this is that my code requires a few local variables which are not accessible from within a new Thread. I could create a new class which extends Thread or implements Runnable so that I can pass the necessary variables in, but that's no longer a simple solution.

Comment: Can you make the local variables you need final or take copies which are final?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize that final variables are accessible from within inner classes. That fixed my problems.

Answer (score 1):

The `readLine()` call indeed is blocking however, the `ready()` call on the `BufferedReader` is not -- so you can check if your reader is ready (non-blocking call) and then perform a read -- something like that:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executablePath);
ProcessWatcher pw = new ProcessWatcher(p);
BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while(!pw.isFinished()) {
  if( output.ready() ) {
    String line = output.readLine();
    if(line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
    // I want to do something in parallel here
}
```

This will allow you to execute something else in the `while` loop while the process is running.

Comment: Hmmm ok, I got fooled by the JavaDoc API then? "[ready() returns] True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for input, false otherwise. Note that returning false does not guarantee that the next read will block. "

Comment: Sorry forgot the link: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready%28%29

Comment: +1: Sorry Liv, ready() is not reliable in all cases, however I tried your code and it works in this case. ;)

Comment: `readLine()` can perform more than one read to get a whole line. `ready()` can return true but `readLine()` blocks to get the whole line. It can also return false, when there would be data if a `read()` triggering a system call was made.  However, if you tested it for this specific case it may behave as desired. ;)

Comment: It's ok don't worry! I was actually thinking myself that if `ready()` returns true that means that there is a character available but it might not be a whole line! so the damn thing can still be blocking after all...

Comment: In that case it only matters if there is a long delay between the start and end of a line. However for applications which print whole lines at a time, this won't be much of a problem.

Comment: The ready() method may not be reliable in all cases, but it worked nicely in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Upon further testing I discovered that this solution is not sufficiently reliable. The line being run in parallel is occasionally starved, so I assume ready() is returning true even if readLine() will be blocking.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you'd be better off putting the "process" spawning stuff in a separate thread of execution since spawning a process can take an indeterminate amount of time, not to mention a plethora of things that can go wrong with it. Having all those stuff bundled in a separate logical unit would be much more cleaner.